# Уязвимость к DoS атакам

Tags: безопасность, dos-атака

Как объединить все программы DoS атак под одну оболочку.

Comment: т.е. где бы взять единый центр управления всеми существующими ботнетами?

Comment: нет, мне в общем то не ДДоС нужен а просто сам ДоС. приследуется целью создание тестирующей программы на уязвимость к ДоС. необходимо объединить несколько программ в одну и создать пользовательский инитерфейс в общем.

Comment: DoS так ДоС) Исправил обратно) На форум АНТИчат лучше с этим вопросом!

Comment: Во-первых, заголовок вопроса не соответствует его телу (непонятно, то ли вам защититься надо, то ли управлять). Во-вторых, вопрос слишком общий (эксплоитов огромное количество, и у каждого свой неповторимый интерфейс управления; а потому непонятно, как вообще к вашей задаче подступиться, ибо мало конкретики).

Comment: А так, посмотрите в сторону Metasploit — это как раз оболочка над написанными специально под неё модулями поиска уязвимостей (в том числе и связанных с DoS). Возможно, отпадёт нужда в разработке собственной оболочки.

Comment: Хотя, кому я это адресую... *\*обратил внимание на дату последнего захода вопрошающего\**.

Answer (score 3):

Я себе это так представляю:

1. для начала в своей программе пишите какой-то общий интерфейс (имеется в виду не графический а интерфейс использования, т.е методы конфигурирования + основные действия start/pause/stop и т.д. и т.п.;
2. для разных консольных приложений делаете разные реализации этого интерфейса;
3. для графических утилит то же самое + придется что-то придумать для того, чтоб можно было программно кликать на кнопки/вводить значения: на винде можно winapi использовать или какие-то фреймворки для тестирования, которые позволяют тестировать GUI в автоматическом режиме;
4. так же создаете окно подключения внешних DoS программ (а если быть точным, то программа + модуль работы с ней, - в котором реализовано то о чем сказано в пунктах 1 и 2;
5. для того, чтоб проверить, правильно ли подключен ваш модуль из пункта 4, надо добавить функционал для прослушивания - для того чтоб проверить, правильно ли подключился модуль на пункте 4, правильно ли работает программа DoS;

А вообще вы должны осознать, что для того, чтоб вам дали конкретный ответ, нужно поставить конкретный вопрос. Ведь очень часто бывает так, что ответ содержится в самом вопросе.

**UPDATE**: вам нужен просто запуск внешнего приложения, что в принципе не является сложной задачей.

(а это более детальное описание того что я вам предлагал сделать)
Я думал вы пишете общий интерфейс для разных утилит с схожим функционалом. напр. : 3-5 консольных приложений с разными параметрами командной строки. напр.: у первой адрес задается так: `-h <hostname>:<port>`, у другой `/hostname <hostname> /port <port>`.

Поэтому и предлагал вам сделать примерно так (псевдо-код):

```
// эта структура данных должна соответствовать элементам GUI интерфейса приложения
class ModuleConfiguration
{
    String hostname
    int port  ;
    int time; // время работы приложения в секундах
    int requests // количество запросов в секунду/минуту
    String executable; // путь к внешней DoS программе    
}

// структура данных 
class ExecConfiguration
{
    String args; // все параметры командной строки для внешней программы
    String executable; // путь к внешней DoS программе    
}

ExecConfiguration convertConfiguration (ModuleConfiguration);
```

У вас есть базовая структура `ModuleConfiguration` - это структура данных, созданная на основе данных, введенных в элементах управления вашего приложения. `ExecConfiguration` - это структура, которая будет использоваться непосредственно кодом, который запускает внешнее приложение. Все что от вас требуется, это создание разных реализаций метода `convertConfiguration` (напр. через подключение внешних модулей или еще как-то). После вы запускаете ваше приложение, используя данные, которые хранятся в структуре `ExecConfiguration`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. у меня вопрос зачем нужен модуль для работы с внешней программой DoS? У каждый из них же есть свой интерфейс. а все что мне нужно это лишь их вызов. в общем я хочу чтобы в интерфейсе был сканеров портов, то же внешний. после основываясь на результаты сканирования мы должны будем вызвать одну из программ данного интерфейса для осуществления непосредственной атаки. Или вы хотели предложить выше описанные процедуры в автоматическом режиме? Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: не могли бы Вы дать пример для простого вызова внешней программы, то есть имеется готовая программа осуществляющая ДоС атаку. необходим ее вызов из разрабатываемого пользовательского интерфейса.

Comment: на каком языке пишете программу? а впрочем не так уж и важно, гуглить надо так:
`<language> запуск внешнего приложения` или `<language> запуск внешней комманды`. вместо language подставляете нужный вам язык

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего сделать это по клиент-серверной архитектуре.

1. Делаете один дос-нод, управляемый по tcp/ip
2. Раскидываете ноды по разным мощностям для увеличения мощности атаки
3. Делаете программу, хранящую список адресов нодов, которая может отправлять нодам команды
4. Посылаете команду к началу атаки, по окончании теста команду к завершению